# Points on plot in R at the wrong location?

Tags: r, graph

[image: Code result of graph]

I'm trying to create a simple code in R that will graph a parabola.

In the graph there will be a parapola and two point marking where it goes through the X axis.
The firdt point (x1) is drawn great but the second point (x2) is drawn... at the same place as x1 despite being negitive at these values.

any help in understanding why this is happening and how to correct it?

```
a=1
b=0
c=-5
curve(a*(x^2)+b*x+c, ylim=c(-10,10), xlim=c(-10,10))
abline(h=0, v=0, lwd=2)
grid()

## Add points at axises
x1<-(-b+sqrt(b^2-4*a*c))/(2*a)
if(!is.nan(x1)){
  p1 <- c(x1, a*(x1^2)+b*x1+c)
  points(t(p1), pch=16)
  text(t(p1), "x1", adj=-1)
}
if(!is.nan(x2)){
  x2<-(-b-sqrt(b^2-4*a*c))/(2*a)
  p2 <- c(x2, a*(x2^2)+b*x2+c)
  text(t(p2), "x2", adj=-1)
}
```

Comment: insert `x2 <- (b-sqrt(b^2-4*a*c))/(2*a)` before your second if condition. R doesn't find x2, that's why it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This isn't the way I draw graphs (I use `ggplot`), but using the online help, I see that the first argument of both `points` and `text` is a vector of x co-ordinates, not an (x, y) pair.  Thus, your calls do not correspond to your intention.

This seems to give what you want:

```
a=1
b=0
c=-5
curve(a*(x^2)+b*x+c, ylim=c(-10,10), xlim=c(-10,10))
abline(h=0, v=0, lwd=2)
grid()

x1 <-(-b+sqrt(b^2-4*a*c))/(2*a)
x2 <-(-b-sqrt(b^2-4*a*c))/(2*a)
text(x=c(x1, x2), y=c(0, 0), labels=c("x1", "x2"), adj=c(-1, -1))
points(x=c(x1, x2), y=c(0, 0))
```

You also have a logical error in your code because `x2` does not exist at the time you test whether it is NaN

[image: Correct output]

Answer (score 0):

you're missing

`points(t(p2), pch=16)` in x2.
The text goes next to a point, no new point means text goes to the same point.

Also instead of 'adj' try using 'pos' to specify where the text should be located in relation to the point.